# Отправить get запрос из календаря в запрос по API

Tags: php, api, get

Есть php код, которым получаю данные по API. В этом коде есть поля с датой начальной и конечной. За этот период приходит ответ с данными. На данный момент даты прописываются вручную в этом коде.

```
    $req->setStartTime('2020-07-03 00:00:00');
    $req->setEndTime('2020-07-03 24:00:00');
    $req->setStatus("Payment Completed");
    $req->setLocaleSite("ru_site");
    $req->setPageNo(1);
    $req->setPageSize(100000);
    $req->setFields("commission_rate,created_time");
    $req->setAppSignature("aaaaa");
    $resp = $c->execute($req);
```

Хочу, чтобы можно было во фронт энде менять даты. Для этого сделал календарь с субмитом, который дает GET запрос.

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="date" name="stardate">
    <input type="date" name="enddate">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как теперь этот GET запрос из календаря впихнуть в PHP GET запрос, который у меня выше? Я представляю это так: нажимаешь на субмит кнопку, страница обновляется и я получаю данные по датам, которые выбрал в календаре.

Comment: Можно использовать ajax-запрос на файл-обработчик. После обработки формировать json с новыми датами, которые потом достать из ответа и вставить в нужные места.

Comment: В поле action формы вставьте адрес скрипта с АПИ. А сюда: $req->setStartTime($_GET[‘stardate’]);
    $req->setEndTime($_GET[‘enddate’]);

Comment: mpakfm, спасибо. Сам уже дошел до этого. Все работает.